# android: how to use "extended resources"?

Tags: android, resources, aapt

In Android,we visit resources by using ResourceId.

when we package resoruce,we use "aapt" command.

such as "aapt package -f -M androidmanifest.xml -S res -I android.jar -F apk.ap_"

ResourceId is like "0x7f010001":
"7f" is packageId
"01" is typeId
"0001" is entryId

I found a command "aapt -x to create extended resources".And The resourceId is like "0x02010001".
As u see, the packageId is "02"!!

when I use -x to create extended resources,then use "AssestManager.addAssetPath" to load the resources file . I also can't show the resources.

so ,how to use "aapt -x"?